# Google colab Runtime error: Failed to initialize SDL

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory

I have been recently getting this colab error. Whenever I run a certain cell the colab notebook throws this error:

```
    RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-feca46536a5c> in <module>()
----> 1 env = gym.make('ALE/Breakout-v5', render_mode='human')
      2 env = Recorder(env, './video')

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gym/envs/atari/environment.py in seed(self, seed)
    194                 "https://github.com/mgbellemare/Arcade-Learning-Environment#rom-management"
    195             )
--> 196         self.ale.loadROM(getattr(roms, self._game))
    197 
    198         if self._game_mode is not None:

RuntimeError: Failed to initialize SDL
```

I have all the necessary libs installed and I have also tried restarting the colab multiple times. Please help.
Thx

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't render some gym environments in colab, the error is probably related to that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).